# Show "..." in HTML table content when the content is too big for its size

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have given my HTML table row space of 200px. But a text of more than that space can be inserted into it. I want my row to display "..." at the end of the row if the content is more then that space.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please read the FAQ on how to properly post questions.

Comment: @Diodeus Even tho the question is pretty naive and short, I don't really see what's wrong with this question. There is no moderation in the different levels of each scripter/programmer. Can you please state what's wrong with the question to make it clearer for Rahul? Thank you kindly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
width: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

in CSS to have the overflowing text be replaced by `...`.

But as it doesn't work for TD elements, you'll have to add another element in between, for example a div.

See [demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ojipod/1/edit).

Answer (score 1):

This is the styling you are looking for.

Good luck!

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Some more here: http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html